# Modifying Logitech's LUA Functions to change modifier

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I'm fairly new to LUA programming, and so far I've managed to use the LUA scripting in logitech's Ghub software to write simple scripts. However I have noticed that the Logitech API restricts us to using their predefined modifiers. For example my code will check if mouse button 5 is pressed, but will not do anything unless mouse 5 is pressed simultaneously with left shift held down, then it will press num1.

Is it possible to do this with a key other than their defined modifiers? ie the script will send num1 when i press mousebutton 5 and the E key simultaneously.

Below is my code:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg, family)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 and IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
      key = "num1"
      PressKey(key)
      Sleep(15)
      ReleaseKey(key)
   end
end
```

Comment: It's impossible.  GHUB is unable to determine whether `E` key is pressed or not.  Only mouse buttons and Shift/Alt/Ctrl are available for monitoring.  And (only if you have Logitech keyboard) special G1,G2,... keyboard keys are also available.

Comment: Perhaps a little off-topic, but it's "Lua" and not "LUA". Lua means Moon in Portuguese, it is not an abbreviation, it's just the name of the language. - http://www.lua.org/about.html#name